# Building multiple boxplots with different string names on x axis and values on y

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-science

So i want to build a boxplot (preferably with seaborn, but you can use any library) that has 'county_name' on x and 'deaths' on y, here's the dataframe:

```
    deaths  cases
country_name        
Austria 609 84909
Belgium 853 66573
Bulgaria    1951    60310
Croatia 863 51483
Cyprus  78  23391
Czechia 2412    108071
Denmark 94  40406
Estonia 208 20884
Finland 66  22581
France  7938    951817
Germany 4886    500498
Greece  2265    127250
Hungary 3985    125906
Iceland 1   1486
Ireland 175 52376
Italy   9282    552558
Latvia  304 21478
Liechtenstein   0   258
Lithuania   439 36487
Luxembourg  51  5212
Malta   48  3980
Netherlands 749 275044
Norway  5   17713
Poland  11166   399129
Portugal    420 77958
Romania 4505    107550
Slovakia    1433    59812
Slovenia    274 30183
Spain   69299   3119260
Sweden  435 74259
```

The code i used was

`holGROUPED = hol.groupby(hol['country_name']).agg({'deaths': 'sum', 'cases': 'sum'})`

to group countries with deaths and cases in certain days

and then i did this:

```
sns.boxplot(data = holGROUPED, x = 'country_name', y = 'deaths')
```

to try and boxplot the datasets ( each country has to be different box), but i got an error:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'country_name'
```

Can someone help me organize the boxplots and give advice how to build multiple boxplots in one graph using strings as x axis.

Comment: When you do a `groupby`, the `countries` move into index. So, changing the x value as `x = holGROUPED.index`` should work

Comment: actually worked lol